# How am I supposed to interpret the results from Apache's ab benchmarking tool?

Tags: apache, scalability, benchmarking

Alright, I've searched everywhere and I can't seem to find a detailed resource online for how to interpret the results from Apache's ab server benchmarking tool. I've run several tests with what I thought were drastically different parameters, but have seen very similar results (I have a hard time thinking that this means my site is scaling perfectly!). If there is a detailed resource someone could point me to, on how to understand the results from this test, or if someone feels like creating one here, I think that would be very useful to me and others.

Answer (score 32):

Frustrating, isn't it? I am trying to do the same thing, see how my newly provisioned and configured dedicated server compares to others.

What I am ending up doing is comparing my current production server (Dual core 4GB RAM) to the new server (Quad core 8GB RAM).

I need to 'play nice' with my side by side comparisons, as the production server is live and I don't want to 'break' the server for my users.

Comparing the current vs new with the following command on a php page that just calls phpinfo(): **ab -kc 20 -t 60**

On my current production server, I see something like the following, where it couldn't complete the task in the given amount of time:

```
Time taken for tests:   60.1234 seconds
Complete requests:  24538
Failed requests:    58
(Connect: 0, Length:    58, Exceptions: 0)
Requests per second:    408.96 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:   48.905 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:   2.445 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
```

VS the following on the new server which completed all the tests in half the amount of time:

```
Time taken for tests:   29.838791 seconds
Complete requests:  50000
Failed requests:    11
(Connect: 0, Length:    11, Exceptions: 0)
Requests per second:    1675.67 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:   11.936 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:   0.597 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
```

Now, this isn't really a 'fair' test, as the current server is handling 20 websites in addition to the benchmark test. Also, it is really only testing apache & php.

Putting this same test against one of my more complex home pages, one that 'feels' slow on the current server, I see the following:
Current Server:

```
Time taken for tests:   60.14170 seconds
Complete requests:  510
Requests per second:    8.50 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:   2353.497 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:   117.675 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
```

New Server:

```
Time taken for tests:   60.18651 seconds
Complete requests:  1974
Requests per second:    32.89 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:   608.092 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:   30.405 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
```

This test is loading a Joomla CMS dynamically generated page. It is a bit more of a 'real world' test. Again, with the new server not dealing with current site traffic, so it's not an apples to apples comparison. I don't want to test much harder or I risk my end user's experience on my sites.

After migrating the sites to the new server, I plan on doing the above tests again so I can see what affect my regular site traffic has on the benchmarking. The same machine's production vs idle benchmark results.

Now, I am also looking at stressing the new server out and making sure that it reacts well.
Running the command **ab -n 50000 -c 200** I am watching the **top** command and seeing how much CPU & memory are being used while also **f5**ing the page in my browser to see if I get any errors and also to get a feel for how long it takes the server to respond.

My first test gave me:

```
Concurrency Level:  200
Time taken for tests:   692.160011 seconds
Complete requests:  50000
Failed requests:    30102
(Connect: 0, Length:    30102, Exceptions: 0)
Write errors:   0
Non-2xx responses:  30102
Total transferred:  456568770 bytes
HTML transferred:   442928962 bytes
Requests per second:    72.24 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:   2768.640 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:   13.843 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:  644.17 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

Note the very high failed request rate. My apache is set to a max of 250 simultaneous requests, but my MySQL was at only 175. MySQL was the failure point here. It couldn't processes all the requests coming from apache. My web browser page loads was giving me a MySQL connection error page on many page refreshes.

So, I bumped up MySQL to 300 simultaneous requests (I had done it already, but had forgotten to restart MySQL, so this turned out to be a good test - I had identified a needed change, and accidentally did an empirical test validating the change's necessity).

The next run gave me the following results:

```
Concurrency Level:      200
Time taken for tests:   1399.999463 seconds
Complete requests:      50000
Failed requests:        5054
   (Connect: 0, Length: 5054, Exceptions: 0)
Write errors:           0
Non-2xx responses:      5054
Total transferred:      1016767290 bytes
HTML transferred:       995713274 bytes
Requests per second:    35.71 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       5599.998 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       28.000 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          709.24 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

This took over twice as long, but the failed requests rate was much much lower. Basically, the server is now configured to be able to handle at least 200 simultaneous page views of one of my site's home page, but it will take 5 seconds a page to serve them. Not great, but much better than the MySQL errors I was getting previously.

During all of this, my server CPU usage is pegging at 100% with the 'load average' hovering upwards of 180. MySQL is using about 8-9% of the CPU and isn't using much of the RAM I've alloted it, as I am just repeatedly hammering the same page, so it's only dealing with a single database. 400MB of the 4GB+ it is configured to grow into. **top** shows the buffers and cached memory usage at about 50% of the total available RAM. So while I am loading the machine up with this test, it's not getting near the overloaded point. Under a real world database usage, MySQL should grab much of the memory I've alloted it, so the server should be pretty close to full load at that point.

My next test was to test apache at the 'full load' of 250 connections **ab -n 50000 -c 250**

```
Concurrency Level:      250
Time taken for tests:   1442.515514 seconds
Complete requests:      50000
Failed requests:        3509
   (Connect: 0, Length: 3509, Exceptions: 0)
Write errors:           0
Non-2xx responses:      3509
Total transferred:      1051321215 bytes
HTML transferred:       1029809879 bytes
Requests per second:    34.66 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       7212.577 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       28.850 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          711.73 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

This is showing similar results to the 200 connection test with the proper MySQL connection cap. This is good to me I think. I don't like the 7 seconds to return a page, but I think I can improve that at the Joomla level by enabling cacheing in Joomla either with APC or Memcache which are both installed but not utilized by Joomla yet.

Trying to push my luck, I thought I would try 300 simultaneous connections. **ab -n 50000 -c 300** The browser shows a long wait for a quick page load. Otherwise, not really much change in the results.

```
Concurrency Level:      300
Time taken for tests:   1478.35890 seconds
Complete requests:      50000
Failed requests:        2266
   (Connect: 0, Length: 2266, Exceptions: 0)
Write errors:           0
Non-2xx responses:      2266
Total transferred:      1079120910 bytes
HTML transferred:       1057241646 bytes
Requests per second:    33.83 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       8868.215 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       29.561 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          712.99 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

I don't know if my interpretation of these results are 'right' or if I am missing something valueable, but with the lack of instruction that I could find, this is what I came up with.

I just used the results to make sure that I got a good response rate - the lack of a perfect response rate concerns me, but I don't know how to see or reproduce the failures in a way I can inspect them.

The slow time per request also concerns me, but I think I can address much of that at the application layer.

I am confident that while the server would slow to a crawl, it could handle a heavy load situation.

Looking at other performance tuning tools like MonYog after these benchmarking tests has also shown me that my current configurations are 'good enough'.

I wish there was a place where people have posted results of  tests I can reproduce with a hardware description and software configs so I know if I am 'competitive' or if I have a lot of work to do yet to best utilize my equipment. Thus, why I am posting my results.

Comment: I think you might be misinterpreting the failed request line, see also my answer .

Comment: Thanks for the clarification amarillion

Comment: are you testing ab on the local machine? Ie - your doing AB on the same machine where the web server is. I only get more than 1k requests per second when i do the apache benchmark on my own computer.

Comment: I tend to use AB locally for tuning. True, it isn't a true test, but there is often times little one can do to 'tune' an internet connection (There are things that can be done, but it's out of scope for this question). If the network is the limiting factor, and you can tune beyond what the network can provide, you basically have  optimized the system as good as is needed.

Answer (score 9):

Please note that for the "failed requests" line, a failed request is determined by comparing the length of subsequential requests against each other. For dynamic website, this doesn't have to mean that the request failed at all! So don't worry about the failed request line.

See also: http://www.celebrazio.net/tech/unix/apache_bench.html

Answer (score 7):

On top of creuzerm answer. Here is a very good link with some more info

https://serverfault.com/questions/274252/apache-ab-please-explain-the-output

Concerning more about the difference between lines

```
Time per request:       7.303 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.730 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Time per request:       7.303 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.730 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
```

the first one is related to the average time for request per concurrent users so if you are making the test for 1000 requests and 200 concurrent users, the first one will be the average time for each 200 request.
the second one is related to the overall request time which is average time over the whole 1000 requests

Answer (score 2):

On a side note, AB is single-threaded (which is OK for old single-Core CPUs like the 2001 Pentium 4).

To test a multi-Core CPU hosting a Web server (Nginx/Lighty using several processes, Apache using several threads), you should rather use Weighttp (which is compatible with AB).

"Weighttp -t 6" will run 6 client threads (by contrast "AB -t 6" would run a 6-second test).

You will get much more relevant results by using several client threads (as many as the number of Webserver workers - which should match the number of CPU Cores of the server box).

Comment: ab allows you to specify the concurrency level. I think this means it is multi-threaded, in the sense you are using here. E.g.

ab -n 1000 -c 10 http://myserver/

will run 100 requests from 10 concurrent requesters, giving 1000 hits in total.

Comment: @Rick-777 It seems `ab` waits for the first bunch of requests to finish before sending the second bunch. So not multi-threaded in the sense of making requests? Also what do you mean by `requester`?

Comment: I haven't studied the source code of `ab`, so I only reported it's on its options. By requester, I simply mean a thread in a very general sense (not all threads are the same).